# Calling method from Activity inside an adapter

Tags: android, interface, adapter

Hi guys this is rather a silly question because i'm confused. what i'm trying to do is to call a method(share to facebook) from an activity inside my adapter.

this is the illustration:

Activity: 
postToFacebook(Pets dog);
listview that holds list of dogs.

Adapter:
adapter in which i use to create custom view for better looking.

problem is that i want to set an onLongClickListener on the LinearLayout that holds all the dog's info (this way user can hold any part of the info) to be shared to facebook.

is there a way to do this?

thanks a lot!

Comment: show us the code please , so we can take a closer look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question you are complety on bad way

In your activity you have an ArrayList (or List) with Dogs information

Something like

```
ArrayList<Pets> listDogs;
```

now, you should do this (myListView is your ListView obj)

```
myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int pos, long id) {
                postToFacebook(listDogs.get(pos));
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In this way you get the position of element selected and call your method from activity and not from adapter.

```
listDogs.get(pos)
```

this line return the element of the row selected.